# Random neural network learning error rate at application start

Tags: c#, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, accord.net

I am just trying to understand a bit how the training of neural network work. I am using `C#` as the language of choice, along with `Accord.NET` library.

**My problem is that:**

Sometimes training error starts with 26% and then you can wait for 30 minutes for it to drop to 25%. The other time - it starts at 3% and drops to 0,1% within half a second. Or it can start at 90% error rate and basically never drop..

**Here is some output example:**

25% error after 10000 iterations (10 seconds). If I have continued - it would be 25% even after 30 minutes..

[image]

1.6% error after 100 iterations (0.5 seconds)

[image]

Close to 0% error within the same old 100 iterations. Closest to perfect result which i want to see upon EVERY run. Not on random occasion!

[image]

With this much instability I don't understand how a fully functional neural network can be created, so I can train it and use it with some meaningful result. What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the code:**

```
        Console.WriteLine("Starting..");

        // initialize input and output values
        double[][] input =
        {
            new double[] {0, 0}, new double[] {0, 1},
            new double[] {1, 0}, new double[] {1, 1}
        };

        double[][] output =
        {
            new double[] {0}, new double[] {1},
            new double[] {1}, new double[] {0}
        };

        // create neural network
        ActivationNetwork network = new ActivationNetwork(
            new SigmoidFunction(2),
            2, // two inputs in the network
            2, // two neurons in the first layer
            1); // one neuron in the second layer

        // create teacher
        var teacher = new ResilientBackpropagationLearning(network);

        // loop
        int ii = 1;
        double error = 1.0;
        while (ii < 100)
        {
            // teach the network
            error = teacher.RunEpoch(input, output);
            Console.WriteLine($"Iteration={ii}. Error={error}");
            ii++;
        }

        // Checks if the network has learned
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            double[] answer = network.Compute(input[i]);
            double answer_short = answer[0];
            double ans_shortened = answer_short < 0.1 ? 0 : Math.Round(answer_short, 2);

            double expected = output[i][0];

            // actual should be equal to expected
            Console.WriteLine($"Expected is {expected}. Actual is {ans_shortened}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: what input are you training it with? random data?  or just the 4 x 2 doubles seen in the code?

Comment: Exactly. Give information on your training set, as it gives better insight on your code (30 minutes vs 0.5 seconds is huge)

Comment: It's a hello-world of almost every neural network - basic XOR operation. See the code. 00 = 1, 01 = 1, 10 = 1, 11 = 0. I am training the network with doubles as seen in the code.

Comment: usually you would define a treshold for the error and train as many iterations as needed to fall below that treshold. but that does not explain the inconsistent behavior you observe. the code is almost identical to [their own samples](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/6fcf77a5-4952-daf8-451e-227766a3fe89.htm). the sigmoid alpha is also correct (2 is the default anyway). I know that AForge initializes neuron weights with random numbers and will try to reproduce your problem and see if it could be related to that.

Comment: I have used this official tutorial from `accord.net` http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Neuro_Learning_ParallelResilientBackpropagationLearning.htm